# C++ Vector of Pointers issue

Tags: c++, pointers, stdvector

I am having trouble understanding what is going wrong with my vector of pointers. Basically, my goal is to pass a vector of pointers to a helper function, and then have that helper function modify fields of the object that the pointer is pointing to. Right now, however, everything is compiling and running, but the objects' values aren't being modified. I have something like this:

```
void Test(std::vector<Result*>& resultsArg){
  std::vector<Result*> storage;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    if(FuncIsTrue()){
       auto* result = resultsArg.at(i);
       storage.push_back(result);
    } else {
       helperFunction(storage);
       storage.clear();
    }
  }
}

void helperFunction(std::vector<Result*>& storage){
  for(Result* r : storage) {
    r->setX(2);
  }
}
```

I think it may have something to do with scope? The linter says that `auto* result` is being passed by const reference to `storage.push_back`, so it could be that the reference is corrupted at the end of the first if statement (since `helperFunction` is called in the else). Is there some way to make copy of the result pointer so that it is maintained in the `storage` vector?

Comment: `std::vector<Result*> storage();` -- This declares a function called `storage` that takes no arguments and returns a `std::vector<Result*>`.  You've just been bit by the most vexing parse.

Comment: Edited the question -- this was a mistype by me and isn't responsible for the issue.

Comment: This is why you should never type in your code, and instead, copy and paste the exact code from your editor to the posting window.  Now we don't know what else could be typed in wrong.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < 10; i ++)` -- where is `i` declared?  Also, please post a [mcve].  There is logic embedded in your function, where you are conditionally calling `helperFunction` based on the value of `FuncIsTrue`.  This may have nothing to do with what you're claiming, and everything to do with the logic not flowing how you believe it is.

Comment: The code compiles so any error like this is not the cause but thanks for pointing this out :). I can't copy/paste because the actual code is company-protected and more complex. This is an over-simplified, cleaned up version.

Comment: Got it -- yes I just tested on an external editor and it seems to be a logic issue but the pointer stuff is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This line doesn't do what you think it does:

`std::vector<Result*> storage();`

That line is a function declaration.  You declared a function called `storage` that takes no arguments and returns a `std::vector<Result*>`.  You did not create a `std::vector<Result*>` vector in that line of code.

The way C++ works is that if the line of code looks like a function declaration, it's a function declaration, even though that line of code looks similar to an object being declared.

---

To fix this, simply use the brace initializer:

`std::vector<Result*> storage{};`

or not have any explicit initialization syntax, since the vector's default constructor creates an empty vector:

`std::vector<Result*> storage;`

Comment: You referenced the "most vexing parse" in your comment, it should probably be part of the answer too.  Even better if you could add a link for more explanation.

Comment: Apologies, this was a mistype by me. This isn't the error!